# Project datasource from separate Class Project not working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

First question here so let's go:

I have made a c# Class Library in which I make use of the entity framework.

If I reference the library i can use the objects of the entity framework in my application.
But if I want to use the dll in a projcet datasource object I can choose the classes I want but if I press Finish, just nothing happens. No error message, nothing.

Can one of you point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

### Update:

The problem only seems to occure when using x64

Comment: Where do you press Finish? In the Add reference dialog?

Comment: No, When i add the project datasource

Answer (score 0):

If your classes derive from types defined in the EntityFramework library (e.g. DbContext), you may access them in your target application only if you add the EF libraries as well. It is because you are providing your own types with your class library derived from types which target application does not know anything about.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I indeed had added the EntityFramework library. I have found that it is working when I use x86 and anyCpu. its only not working when I use x64. I think i will use anyCPU for now because it's working but i did like to know why it's not working on x64.